# Rpi3 missing spi-bcm2708 module

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, spi

I installed Raspbian `4.1.18-v7+` on my new RPi 3 and WiFi works great however when I proceed with instructions for connecting the MCP3009 ADC I don't find spi-bcm2708 listed in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`, nor do I find any spi module when I search with `lsmod | grep spi`.

Hmm... is SPI not supported anymore?

Edit:

Thanks, Steve and Joan.  I now see "dtparam=spi=on" was appended to /boot/config.txt by raspi-config just as you predicted.  Now I see spi_bmc2835 is listed in lsmod.

My MCP3008 tool is able to open the /dev/spidev0.0 device but fails to write SPI structures via ioctl() which returns errno=22 "Invalid parameter."

Also, spidev_test loopback test fails (MISO <-> MOSI connected).
The output data is all "00 00 00 ..." when we are expecting "FF FF FF ...".
I did a full update and rpi-update with reboot but results are still negative results.

I attached my oscilloscope to SCLK, MIOS, MOSI, CE0, but do not even see a glimmer of a triggered signal as the tests are run.

I double checked my connections and verified 3.3VDC power level.

Is there some way to take a closer look at the state of the spidev module?
Would you know how to enable a kernel trace on it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

The module spi-bcm2708 has been replaced with the updated kernel module spi-bcm2835.

Generally you should no longer load modules with modprobe or by putting them in /etc/modules (there are exceptions).

Recent kernels use a method called device tree.

SPI is now enabled by adding the following line to `/boot/config.txt`

`dtparam=spi=on`

Note, the above is what raspi-config is doing "behind the scenes".

See /boot/overlays/README for general device tree information.

Answer (score 4):

SPI is still supported, however recent versions of Raspbian have changed how SPI and other interfaces are enabled. To enable SPI run `sudo raspi-config`

1. select option **9 Advanced Settings**
2. then option **A6 SPI**
3. Choose **Yes** to enable the SPI Interface
4. Then **OK**
5. Then **Yes** to load the module by default
6. click **OK**

Finally click **Finish** to exit `raspi-config` and reboot.

Comment: This is now *5 Interfacing Options* then *P4 SPI*

Answer (score 0):

After trying a second RPi3 and my RPi2B+ I discovered my problem was that I had been using the 26-pin GPIO reference diagram rather than the 40-pin GPIO reference.  Silly me.  Thanks to all.